# Sequence Generation formula in excel for an “exploder” function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am wondering if there is a way to create the following type of sequence in excel:

```
1    1
2    1
2    2
3    1
3    2
3    3
4    1
4    2
4    3
4    4
5    1
5    2
5    3
5    4
5    5
```

I would ideally like to be able to generate this sequence up to any reasonable limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming A1 as value 1 and B1 also has value 1, on A2 inserts the following formula:

```
=IF(A1=B1,A1+1,A1)
```

[image]

Then, insert on B2 the formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>B1,A1=B1),1,B1+1)
```

[image]

Select A2 and B2, then drag the formulae down to fill the other cells.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew it was stupidly straightforward but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

For column A, you can use a formula of the form
`=INT(SQRT(ROW()*2)+1/2)`
(see details in [**OEIS A002024**](http://oeis.org/A002024)).

The formula for column B can be written a little more simply - `=IF(A2=A1;B1+1;1)` (starting from the second row - for the first row, in B1 just write 1)